# Injected CDI Bean return null values

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

My JSF Page:

```
<h:form>
    <p>
        <h:outputLabel for="phone">Phone: <h:message class="alert" for="phone"/> 
            <h:message class="alert" for="phoneLogin"/>
        </h:outputLabel>
        <p:inputText id="phone" value="#{userBean.mobile_phone}">
            <f:validator validatorId="phoneValidation"/>
        </p:inputText>
        <p:watermark for="phone" value="+79123456789"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <h:outputLabel for="password">
            Password: <h:message class="alert" for="password"/>
        </h:outputLabel>
        <p:password id="password" value="#{userBean.password}">
            <f:validator validatorId="passValidation"/>
        </p:password>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center">
        <p:commandButton id="phoneLogin" update="@form" binding="#{dataBean.phoneLogin}" 
                         value="Login" action="#{dataBean.loginProfile}"/>
    </p>
</h:form>
```

My `UserBean` code:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@SessionScoped
    //user data. getters and setters
```

My `DataBean` code:

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@Stateless
public class DataBean{

@Inject
private UserBean userBean;
//class logic
```

When I press the button I should be logged in by `loginProfile` method in `DataBean` class. But the `@Inject` annotation returns `null` values and I get a `NullPointerException`. All imports are ok. I'm using CDI beans only and I'm really not understanding why I can't get the values from `UserBean` class. I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: is your DataBean in the same war?

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman Nope

Comment: Well in JEE 6 you can package ejb's in war. And that should resolve your problem.

Comment: Using Named and Stateless in the same bean doesn't have any sense and is most probably the cause of your problem.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman Yesterday everything was okay. It's not package problem, I'm sure.

Comment: If the problem is simply that you didn't do a clean build, then it should be closed as "too localized".  Neither the Question or the Answer is likely to be of use to other people.

Comment: @StephenC Yeah, but I'm not see link for closing. Maybe my rate is too slow?

Comment: @rubaka - My comments was reall for other readers.  You don't have enough rep points to "vote to close" ... and I don't think you can delete your own question if it has non-deleted answers.

Answer (score 1):

If program not working, but you sure that everything is ok. Try to clean target directory and try one more. It's working for me.

Comment: Are you saying that the solution to your problem was to do a clean build?

Comment: @ChrisF Yes. I can't believe that I was changing code more than one hour and problem was in that :( Very sad.

Comment: Excellent! this works for me ( i'm using Netbeans + TomEE) , thanks